# Meteor update collection with object

Tags: javascript, object, meteor, collections

Is it possible to update a collection with an object? I've tried this below. It'd doesn't throw an error but it doesn't update either. Any suggestions?

```
var data = {
    songTitle: 'Blah Blah',
    songTime: '1:30'
}

Songs.update({
    _id: songId,
    createdBy: currentUser,
},
{
    $set: {data}
 });
```

Comment: I guess you should add more information... can you post the log of the database?

Comment: you don't need to add those `{}` you can just : `$set: data`

Comment: Ah! That was it, yeah removed the braces and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [referene](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/):

you don't need to add those {} you can just : $set: data